# Problem with set parameters for create bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap

I have screen 240x128.
When i create screen 256x128 everythink is ok.

```
AppScreen = new byte[3 * 1024 * 32];
rawStride = (256 * PixelFormats.Rgb24.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
myScreen = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap(256, 128, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Rgb24, null);
myScreen = BitmapSource.Create(256, 128, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Rgb24, null, AppScreen, rawStride);
```

for 240 i do it that:

```
AppScreen = new byte[3 * 1024 * 32 - (16*3)];
rawStride = (240 * PixelFormats.Rgb24.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
myScreen = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap(240, 128, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Rgb24, null);
myScreen = BitmapSource.Create(240, 128, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Rgb24, null, AppScreen, rawStride);
```

But I see black line when screen should by full green.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiPIk.png)

```
    private void ScreenInit()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i++)
        {
            BizonScreen[i] = 0;
        }
        ScreenColor = Colors.LightGreen;
        RenderScreen();
    }
    private void RenderScreen()
    {

        /* Przepisanie z bitowej struktury na format  */
        for (uint x = 0; x < 240; x++)
        {
            for (uint y = 0; y < 128; y++)
            {
                 SetPixel(x, y, ScreenColor);
            }
        }

        this.myScreen = BitmapSource.Create(240, 128, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Rgb24, null, AppScreen, rawStride);
        this.myScreen.Freeze();
        this.InvokeIfRequired((value) => Image_Screen.Source = value, this.myScreen);
    }
    private void SetPixel(uint X, uint Y, Color Color)
    {
        AppScreen[(X * 3) + (Y * 768)] = Color.R;
        AppScreen[(X * 3) + (Y * 768) + 1] = Color.G;
        AppScreen[(X * 3) + (Y * 768) + 2] = Color.B;
    }
```

Edit:

```
    AppScreen = new byte[3 * 1024 * 30];
    AppScreen[(X * 3) + (Y * 3*240)] = Color.R;
    AppScreen[(X * 3) + (Y * 3*240) + 1] = Color.G;
    AppScreen[(X * 3) + (Y * 3*240) + 2] = Color.B;
```

and work for 240.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a byte array for your AppScreen variable which is:

```
AppScreen = new byte[3 * 1024 * 32];
```

You can rewrite 3 * 1024 * 32 as 3 * 256 * 128, so above code matches the amount of memory required for a 256x128 canvas, since each pixel is 3 bytes (PixelFormats.Rgb24)

Now you want a different canvas, not 256x128 but 240x128, so your byte array needs to match the memory required for this different canvas size, therefore if i'd allocate it similarly as you did before:

```
 AppScreen = new byte[3 * 960 * 32];
```

You could rewrite this other memory allocation 3 * 960 * 32 as 3 * 240 * 128, or 3 * canvaswidth * canvasheight. It probably also would be better to set the canvaswidth and canvasheight or define them as parameters for a method, so your code would be reusable.